# Cant get request payload in express js node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my Node  Express Code,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var fs = require('fs');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        port = 8112;


    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.listen(port);


    app.route('/abc')
        .post(abc);


    function abc(req,res){
        console.dir(req.body);
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }

})();
```

But Im getting request body as

> {}

But in my network Tab in Chrome I can see request payload.
    Please note OPTIONS is fired before this POST call.

Request headers

> POST /abcHTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8112 Connection:
>   keep-alive Content-Length: 11 Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Origin: http://localhost:4200 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
>   x-api-key:CExkxDlFC35ckfCGX6m61x76GxIYH2h2Iv8bX874
>   Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
>   Accept: */* Referer:
>   http://localhost:4200/dashboard 
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

**Request Payload**

> {"dd":"dd"}

Comment: Can you show your request? including headers, please. (Update your question wit it)

Comment: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");` are pointless as you are using the cors middleware.

Comment: `Content-Type: text/plain` should probably be `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to send: `Content-Type: application/json` for `bodyParser.json()` to work, without it, your JSON payload won't be parsed, that's why you get: `{}`

From the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions):

> The bodyParser object exposes various factories to create middlewares.
>   All middlewares will populate the req.body property with the parsed
>   body when the Content-Type request header matches the type option, or
>   an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type
>   was not matched, or an error occurred.

Example using `.fetch`:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4200/dashboard', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({dd: 'dd'})
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your content-type header is text/plain. Please try  replacing

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

with

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

Answer (score 3):

This normally happens because of the "Content-type" header in your http request.

**JSON Bodies** 
bodyParser.json() only accepts the type of "application/json" and rejects other non-matching content types.

**Solutions 1: Accepting Extra Content Types Other Than `application/json`** 
check your request header "Content-type" and add it to options argument in bodyParser.json([options]) in server.

for example if you have this: 
"Content-type: application/csp-report"

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: ["application/json", "application/csp-report"] }));
```

you can also use the built-in middleware in exprss v4.16.0 onwards:

```
app.use(express.json({ type: ['application/json', 'application/csp-report'] }));
```

for more information see [this documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json)
**Notice:**  use this approach only where you can not change `Content-type` to `application/json`.

**Solutions 2 ( recommended ): Change Header `content-type` To `application/json` In Http Request.**

**What about urlencoded bodies ?**
This is similar to json bodies with two differences:

1. "Content-type" header accepted in request is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2. body payload is a url encoded format (Not a json object):
   Format: **param_1=value_1&param_2=value_2&...**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

see [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded).

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Pradhaban Nandhakumar, I think you have to pass data as row data.
Try below code snippets.

**You should always pass raw data .**

`app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.body);
   });`

Answer (score 0):

You are posting a plain-text string instead of a JSON. Consider showing us how you are posting data (jQuery, Fetch API, etc).

Just have to specify

```
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

in your request headers (front-end). The Express body parser should then be able to detect the valid JSON and print the result. Note that `Accept` isn't required but it instructs the server that the client understands and accepts a JSON response.

Alternatively, use a simple library like [Easy Fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-fetch-api) on the front-end to manage server-side calls without having to deal with response parsing or header settings.