# NodeJS req.body is always empty

Tags: node.js, express, postman, body-parser

> My server.js code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

const AboutController = require('./controllers/AboutController');
app.use('/about', AboutController);
```

> AboutController.js

```
router.post('/store', (req, res, next) => {
    // GETTING REQUEST DETAILS AND INITIALIZATION
    let content         = req.body.content;
    let company_name    = req.body.company_name;
    console.log(req.body);
});
module.exports = router;
```

> Problem

**req.body** always return `{}` which is empty object and I don't know why!

> What I have tried

I have tried to `console.log(req)` and it returned objects but still the `body` object is empty!

> Client Side Request

I am using Postman **form-data** to simulate client request.

Comment: You have not specified, how you perform client-side request. What is it, you utilize `form` in HTML? Or you test it with Postman, or you mock requests?

Comment: Show the client side request, otherwise it's not possible to tell what you're doing wrong, you're probably not sending the correct content-type, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606001/cant-get-request-payload-in-express-js-node/50606219#50606219

Comment: yeah, like, well obviously, the problem is there. The middleware you use tries to parse body payload as JSON, but you probably send form-data or multiparts on accident.

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg you are right i will edit my question.. and I am using Postman

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I have edited my question and you are right

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg yea I am using form-data by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your Postman request didn't work is because you aren't parsing a `form-data` type anywhere in your app. The only middleware that you have for parsing is `bodyParser.json()`, which as it says on the tin, parses JSON. For example, if you wanted to parse `x-www-form-urlencoded`, you could use `bodyParser.urlencoded()`.

If you want what you currently have to work, you need to send it JSON, not `form-data`

Regardless, the `form-data` type is normally used for larger payloads (ex: files)

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution..

I was using Postman and I was using **form-data** instead of **raw** and **json** and it worked fine I don't know why yet!

Comment: Well somewhere it got misused.