# express parsing json with body-parse

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to use body-parse version 1.18.3 with express to parse a json post. In app.js I've included it like so

## app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

...

//App setup
var app = express();

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'secretletters', cookie: {}}))

app.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.session.username) {

  } else {

  }

  res.send({'status': 'ok'})
});
```

and in my script on the frontend send a username back to it

```
$('.login-btn').click(function() {
    let username = $('.username').val();

    if (username == '') {
        $('.login-error').removeClass('hidden');
        return null;
    }
    //if passed hide error
    $('.login-error').addClass('hidden');

    var data = {
        'username': username
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response){
           
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            
        },


    });

    /* End Ajax Call */


});
```

It send the username successfully, here's a screenshot of the results of the post request from the network tools

[image]

the bug is when on `console.log(req.body);` on `app.post` I get back and empty `{}` dict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant get request payload in express js node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606001/cant-get-request-payload-in-express-js-node)

Comment: Check that question, You're missing `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: And with the newer version of Express, you do not require `body-parser`. `express.json()` middleware is there